# Что значит «8396b8dd-df0a-49ad-b5ea-31cd992c0793» в ссылке?

Tags: .net, ado.net

Что значит `8396b8dd-df0a-49ad-b5ea-31cd992c0793` в ссылке? Видно, что в первой и во второй ссылке структура этого кода похожа:

```
http://cbsmedia.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/8396b8dd-df0a-49ad-b5ea-31cd992c0793/Lesson 2.ism/manifest

http://cbsmedia.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/ddafddff-0580-4dcf-a64f-fad483f04cab/Lesson 13.ism/manifest
```

Comment: Похоже на [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_Microsoft)

Comment: @Sergiks: Он самый и есть: http://ideone.com/BFWPr5

Comment: Вот здесь хорошо об этом написано: http://tsya.ru/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это Guid - уникальный идентификатор. Очень часто используется в разных местах, например COM библиотеки и классы под своими уникальными номерами регистрируются в реестре операционной системы. Гарантируется что генерируемые Guid-ы всегда уникальны. Подробнее про эти конструкции почитайте например в википедии. В данном случае - те кто выложил показанные в ссылках уроки ('Lesson') - не заморачивался с названиями папок, а использовал для этого уникальные идентификаторы. Теории заговора и секретности - тут нет.
Вы спрашиваете - Как создаются? - есть генераторы таких чисел, например такой встроен в Visual Studio. Внутри - это генератор случайных чисел и наверно туда замешивается время